# Que no se ejecute un TimerTask a la vez

Tags: java

Tengo varias tareas creadas cada 20 segundos, lo que necesito es que no se solapen para que no se reproduzca el audio a la vez.
¿Hay alguna forma de saber si la tarea esta a run?

```
    private void falloVibrador1Prueba(ResultSet rs) {
    try {
        rs.next();
        if (rs.getRow() != 0) {
            if (activoVibrador1 == false) {

                if (rs.getInt(1) == 1 && rs.getInt(2) > 0) {
                    if (jchIgVibrador1.isSelected()) {
                        timerTaskVibrador1 = new TareaVibrador1(rs.getInt(2));
                        timerVibrador1 = new Timer(true);
                        timerVibrador1.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTaskVibrador1, 0, 20000);
                        activoVibrador1 = true;
                        jbVibrador1.setBackground(Color.RED);
                    }
                }
            }
            if (rs.getInt(2) == 0 && activoVibrador1 == true) {
                activoVibrador1 = false;
                timerVibrador1.cancel();
                jbVibrador1.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.err.println("" + ex);
    }
}
```

CLASE DE LA TAREA

```
public class TareaVibrador1 extends TimerTask {

    int zonaFallo;
    AudioVibrador audioVibrador = new AudioVibrador();

    public TareaVibrador1(int zonaFallo) {
        this.zonaFallo = zonaFallo;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        eventoFalloVibrador1();

    }

    public void eventoFalloVibrador1() {
        switch (zonaFallo) {
            case 1:
                audioVibrador.playFalloVibrador1Reponer();
                break;
            case 2:
                audioVibrador.playFalloVibrador1Atasco();
                break;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Puedes enseñar el código que tienes hasta el momento?

Comment: @Error404 he modificado la pregunta. Gracias de antemano

Comment: podrías hacer que cada una de las tareas se ejecute en un intervalo diferente para que no se solapen, sabiendo lo que dura cada audio que ejecutas podrías elegir el intervalo para que no coincidan

Comment: @Joacer acabo de editar la pregunta, tengo varias tareas, si solo tuviera 2 con lo que me has comentado se solucionaría, pero al haber mas ... no se como solucionarlo

Comment: @R.Priego ahora estoy en el trabajo, pero cuando salga intentaré investigar a ver si hay alguna forma de hacerlo.

Comment: @Joacer muchas gracias.

Comment: Te recomiendo uses un ExecutorService en vez de un timer, así solo un hilo correrá a la vez.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409932/java-timer-vs-executorservice

Comment: @Ajeno Gracias, voy a echarle un vistazo.

Comment: También puedes consultar el método join de los hilos [Join in Java] (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/join.html), permite sincronizar dos hilos hasta que no termine el primero no se ejecuta el segundo.

Answer (score 0):

lo mas ideal en este caso es programar un monitor de hilos, sin embargo podrías implementar el siguiente código, el cual es un ciclo donde se consulta cada segundo el estado del hilo

```
    while (timerTaskVibrador1.getState() != Thread.State.TERMINATED) {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
```

esto lo que hace es que crea un punto de pausa hasta que el hilo timerTaskVibrador1 cambie el estado a terminado